# Jquery filter is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="div1">
<input id="input1">
<select multiple="multiple" id="select1">
    <option value="sandeep">sandeep</option>
    <option value="ram">ram</option>
    <option value="raj">raj</option>
    <option value="pak">pak</option>
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="dog">dog</option>
    <option value="cat">cat</option>
    <option value="journey">journey</option>
    <option value="mahesh">mahesh</option>
</select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectClone1;
    selectClone1 = $('#select1 option').clone();
    $('#input1').on('keyup', function(){
        $('#select1 option').remove();
        var value = $(this).val();

        selectClone1.filter(function(index, element){
                console.log('index : '+index);
                console.log('element : '+element);
                return value == '' || element.value.indexOf(value) >= 0;
            }).appendTo('#select1');
    });

    $('#select1').on('click', function(){
            var option = $('option:selected', this).clone();
            $('option:selected', this).remove();
            selectClone1 = $.grep(selectClone1, function(el){return el.value == option[0].value}, true);
</script>
```

I am working on the search functionality along with removal of options when user clicked on option. The above code is working properly for search but when i clicked an option to delete from select box after search for a value, parameters of filter function(index, element) getting exchanged. Due to it error is coming. Can you help me guys where i am missing the point.

Comment: I have a requirement to use JQuery only. @PankajParkar

Comment: my bad, I thought its angular question as you added `angularjs` tag, let me remove that as well

Comment: using `click` on a select will fire twice and is not a good practice...in fact it's fairly useless. What is behavior wanted exactly? Also don't think you want to overwrite `selectClone1`

Comment: Sure, thank you @PankajParkar, I thought if i use angular js i may get help from some more persons right, so i added it. That too people who are entering in to angular means might have the experience of working with Jquery so simply i added.

Comment: @Sandeepsandy no..tags should only be relevant to the specific code problem and nothing else

Comment: When user clicks on the select box options should gets removed from select box and from clones also because when user deleted a character from input box even though we removed from select box it will remains in clone right, so it will come automatically while removing each char from input box. So, if i remove it from clone also i won't get it any more. So i wouldn't see the clicked option select box. @charlietfl

Comment: well use `change` not `click`. Create a demo for this

Comment: @charlietfl, Thank you for correcting me.
After searching for an element in select box through input box, index and element (1, object) of filter function is properly coming. But when i clicked any option, index and element (object, 1) of filter function are getting interchanged so error is getting raised.

Comment: also don't think `$.grep` is what you want here...try using `filter()`

Comment: I used $.grep for removing option from clones. And tried with 'change' instead of 'click' same error came. You want me to use another way other than $.grep to remove a particular option from clone array? I am not aware to create a demo in stack over flow. I will try to create. @charlietfl

Comment: can put this in jsfiddle.net quite easily

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl https://jsfiddle.net/meenuga/0oxz8srk/. First time i am using taken time to use it. I placed the code can you take a look in to it.

Comment: change seems to work fine...is there another problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125030/discussion-between-sandeep-sandy-and-charlietfl).

Comment: Thank you @Nikhil Mishra, You helped me alot. Still I am trying to fix the issue. Your solution given me a way to move ahead.

So, as per your suggestion need to use
selectClone1.splice($.inArray( option[0], selectClone1 ), 1);

Rather than
selectClone1 = $.grep(selectClone1, function(el){return el.value == option[0].value}, true);

I think, some issue is there with grep.

Any way your solution solved my issue. 

Some people given me negative score for my question, I don't know their intention but at least you identified the issue and given a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use Array's splice method for removing element from main array and no need to clone.

```
$('#select1').on('click', function(){
        var option = $('option:selected', this);
        $('option:selected', this).remove();
        selectClone1.splice($.inArray( option[0], selectClone1 ), 1);
});
```